# How to know if the angular 4 click event is triggered using chrome developer tools?

Tags: angular, angular4-forms

I have the following html tag in my app.component.html page

```
<a (click)='clicked=0' style='border-style: solid; padding: 5px 50px 5px 50px;' routerLink='/route/show'>Show Details</a>
```

but when I load this page in my chrome and look at the html in chrome development tools then it is showing below

```
<a routerlink="/route/show" style="border-style: solid; padding: 5px 50px 5px 50px;" ng-reflect-router-link="/route/show" href="#/route/show">Show Details</a>
```

Why it is not showing my (click)=='clicked=0' in chrome developer tools. Is there anything that I miss to see it, I am using angular 4. Thanks.

Comment: Make a function and write in console each time.

Comment: Ok I will do that, thanks for responding, but why the chrome is not showingup that (click)=='clicked=0'

Comment: Actually I cannot understand what it means. Clicked=0 means nothing for me since it does nothing. Seems like just a text, while `click` is meant to call some function

Comment: I want to set a flag upon clicking that link, clicked is a flag which will set to 0 upon clikcing that link. It is not optimal to call a function for setting a single flag right

Comment: You're just executing a line of code on click, there's a variable in your component.ts side (controller) called `clicked: number`, that is assigned value 0 on click. I prefer calling a function `(click)="onClick()"`. You can show it by defining a function that prints it `onClick() { console.log(this.clicked) }`

Comment: @lancovici Thanks, sure I will call a function to set the flag, but why it is not shownup in chrome developement tools, any idea,

Comment: If you want to output a message to the console when setting `clicked = 0`, you can define `clicked` as a public property of the component class, and put a call to `console.log` in the setter of that property.

Comment: The question was (obviously) why isn't it showing in the DOM as debug info and not how it internally works. Is there any built in way to activate this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At compile time, the `(click)` event binding gets transmuted into an event listener and is no longer visible as an attribute like in:

```
<a (click)='clicked=0' ...
```

The exact same as your `routerLink` gets transmuted to `ng-reflect-router-link`

If you open dev tools, inspect the element and then open the *Event Listeners* tab, you will see the event has been bound and you can trace it through to the (most likely) anonymous function which has been generated to handle `clicked = 0`.

Comment: In Event Listeners tab it show zone.js events instead of given event on click. Even that zone.js event is very ambiguous.